# JS - Unbinding click action from element nested inside item that should be clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site where I want to have a sub menu show when the heading is clicked and hide it again if they click the heading again.

However, I want to be able to click inside the submenu without it disappearing as the `Items` in the snippet below are not just list items but dropdowns etc,.

I tried adding `$("#menu > li:nth-child(1) > ul").unbind("click");` to get around this but it does not work.

```js
$("#menu > li:nth-child(1)").on("click", function(){
  $("#menu > li:nth-child(1) > ul").unbind("click");
  if($("#menu > li:nth-child(1) > ul").css("display") == 'none'){
    $("#menu > li:nth-child(1) > ul").fadeIn("slow");
  }else{
    $("#menu > li:nth-child(1) > ul").fadeOut("slow");
  }
});

$("#menu > li:nth-child(2)").on("click", function(){
  $("#menu > li:nth-child(2) > ul").unbind("click");
  if($("#menu > li:nth-child(2) > ul").css("display") == 'none'){ 
    $("#menu > li:nth-child(2) > ul").fadeIn("slow");
  }else{
    $("#menu > li:nth-child(2) > ul").fadeOut("slow");
  }
});

$("#menu > li:nth-child(3)").on("click", function(){
  $("#menu > li:nth-child(3) > ul").unbind("click");
  if($("#menu > li:nth-child(3) > ul").css("display") == 'none'){
    $("#menu > li:nth-child(3) > ul").fadeIn("slow");
  }else{
    $("#menu > li:nth-child(3) > ul").fadeOut("slow");
  }
});
```

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

#menu > li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#menu > li > ul{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>
  Menu 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  Menu 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  Menu 3
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `event.stopPropagation()`.

From MDN docs:

> Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

The example below shows that when you click each menu item, it does not fire the click event for it's parent elements.

```js
$("#menu > li").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).find("> ul").fadeToggle("slow");
});

$("#menu > li > ul").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#menu>li>ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    Menu 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu 3
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: I changed the JS slightly, if you wish to use the original, you just want the last 3 lines :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code to use just one click event for all `li's` and use `e.stopPropagation();` to stop the event bubbling while you click on sub `li` items

```js
 $("#menu li ul").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
        $("#menu li").on("click", function (e) {
          
            var ul = $(this).find("ul");
            //$("ul").unbind("click");
            if ($(ul).css("display") == 'none') {
                $(ul).fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                $(ul).fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });
```

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

#menu > li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#menu > li > ul{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>
  Menu 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  Menu 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  Menu 3
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a small update to your DOM and it will work as below,

```js
$('#menu> li > span').click(function(){
  $(this).next('ul').toggle();
})


$('.child-menu > li').click(function() {
 alert($(this).html());

})
```

```css
ul,li{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

#menu > li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  cursor:pointer
}

#menu > li > ul{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <span>Menu 1</span>
    <ul class="child-menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span>Menu 2</span>
    <ul class="child-menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span>Menu 3</span>
    <ul class="child-menu">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```